# Return multiple selections from a Slicer (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I have this issue where I'm trying to pull (selected) values from a slicer column...and the slicer has let's say 10 types of fruit. If i click on the fruit i want it to populate in another cell/output. So I need to write a code that returns the string of selections that I have defined the from the slicer. So if the slicer contains selections of apples, bananas, and pears. It should be populated in the output cell and separated by commas and look like the following: apples, bananas, pears. Any thoughts?

Comment: Please begin by posting your current code.

Comment: Jweaks, I honestly don't even know where to begin or start...could you give me an idea on how I should get started? Sorry for being so vague about this, I really am having a tough time articulating the issue..

Comment: If you have no VBA experience, this isn't the best forum. The moderators like to keep it a place where you post you code citing a problem your having and inviting improvements/tweaks... not a place where a non-coder asks someone to write some code for them. I don't even understand exactly what you're wanting to setup from your description.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the *Name property* of a *Slicer Item Object*.
To do that, you need to access your particular *SlicerCache Object* within 
the *SlicerCaches Collection* of the *Workbook Object*.
Then iterate through each visible item using *VisibleSlicerItems Property* to get individual item names.

Something like:

```
Sub GetSlicerItems()
    Dim s As SlicerCache
    Dim sItm As SlicerItem, myitems As String

    Set s = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Name")
    For Each sItm In s.VisibleSlicerItems
        If myitems = "" Then myitems = sItm.Name Else _
            myitems = myitems & ", " & sItm.Name
    Next
    Debug.Print myitems
End Sub
```

Where do you get the **Slicer_Name**? It's on *Slicer Settings* under *Name to use in formula:*. HTH.